# What is the grouping I seen in the Graph tab on Dask's Dashboard

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

For each DTO my Flask Web Server accepts, I create a new Dask Graph and run the Graph on the DTO. The runtime of the graph is 8 seconds. A single graph looks like this: [image: A single Dask Graph]

When I stream DTOs to the web server, 1 each second, my graphs look like this: [image: Dasks Graphs]

is looks like there is some kind of grouping to the graphs. What is it?

Comment: Hi, could you give us at least a code snippet to try to explain why there is a grouping in each of your graph?